# Why isn't Daisuke affected by Risa Harada in the first episode?

Tags: d.n.angel

I watched the pilot episode of D.N. Angel. The first episode explains that Daisuke, when fourteen, learns that whenever he sees the person he loves/likes (in this case Risa Harada) or even just a picture of her, he turns into Dark who was a thief last seen 40 years ago. Why is it that sometimes in the first episode he doesn't turn into Dark even though he sees Risa, especially at school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is because he turns fourteen later on in the episode;  the curse does not pass until the guy is fourteen(yes, one does count the entire day as the day for celebrating birthday, but was born at one particular hour). That's why I think Daisuke didn't turn into Dark.

Comment: hmmmm good point